# How do I write a LDAP Query to search an OU for users that do NOT have an email address?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I know how to search AD to find all users with an email address but I need to include the syntax for a LDAP Query, can you help? Also, how would I export this list to excel?

Comment: Have you tried (!(mail=*))?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to determine an empty or null value using an LDAP query - what you would have to do is query all users, then write some business logic to find the ones with empty values in the `mail` property.

Finding all of them is quite easy, you could simply do :

`(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*))`

Comment: He isn't asking about empty/null attribute values, which don't exist in LDAP anyway. (!(mail=*)) should work according to [RFC 4511](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4511#section-4.5.1)

Comment: I think the question summary and description could be interpreted differently, and certainly doesn't warrant a down-vote. Also, `NULL` certainly does exist in Active Directory, and can be set using the `PutEx` command, so please get your facts straight. Also, I'm not sure how useful your query is, as it returns every single entity that does not have the mail property listed on the DirectoryEntry.